# My fragment restart the application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem. I am trying to change a fragment when a user clicks on it, but it does not work. I do not see the mistake but It works for another fragment. Here is my code :

**Fragment where I try to switch: **

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil, container, false);
    TextView textViewNom = view.findViewById(R.id.labelNom);
    textViewNom.setText(((Main)getActivity()).getNomComplet());
    linearScore = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearScore);
    linearScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        fragment_score frag_score= new fragment_score();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag_score,"scorefrag");
        transaction.addToBackStack("scorefrag");
        transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    linearReglage = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearReglage);
    linearReglage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment_reglage frag_reglage= new fragment_reglage();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag_reglage,"reglagefrag");
            transaction.addToBackStack("reglagefrag");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

To explain you I do not have problem when I click on linearScore in the view but my application restarts when I try to click on linearReglage.

linearReglage (XML) :

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="layout.fragment_reglage">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="oui"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>

</ScrollView>
```

**fragment_reglage (java):**

```
public class fragment_reglage extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reglage, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }

}
```

I do not see an error I just have a Failed exception ( because of non-0 exit status). But the application restart like if it was basic. 
I do know what is this error and if it is link

Comment: Can you show us the error log?

Comment: Is it not related to that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896161/getting-w-art-failed-execv-error-when-i-add-an-imageview/43207019

Comment: What i get here is from fragment linearscore ur replacing to linear relage. I would have done it via activity and not from a fragment

Comment: 02-01 16:21:17.233 13076-13076/woowin.woowin W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/woowin.woowin-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@woowin.woowin-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
@Zelig63

Comment: @Eselfar I saw it but it does not work

Comment: @Jileshl I do not think that the problem come from the fragment beacause it works with another

Comment: If it works with `fragment_score` try to start `fragment_score` with both buttons and see what happens. And please follow the naming convention (should be `ScoreFragment`)

Comment: @Eselfar it works :/

Comment: So your problem is the Fragment

Comment: @PierreColart you are testing your app on an emulator or a real time device!.. judging by the only code of yours you are adding a FRAGMENT OVER A FRAGMENT and then adding the another fragment that is already in the stack memory!  that might be causing the issue of dex cache

Answer (score 1):

as @Eselfar in the comment recommended you to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896161/getting-w-art-failed-execv-error-when-i-add-an-imageview/43207019)

using the dex solution and trying it on a real device this cache error would be long gone probably!  but to me everything seems fine in the code except the cache mechanism you are trying using the backStack along add option

see **[this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)** for back stack management

I think this code will solve the problem of yours

just change the fragmentTransaction.add to fragmentTransaction.replace because from your code you are trying to navigate between two fragments replacing will keep the cache maintained

do that and test on real device..

here how your code will look like after the change

```
       @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil, container, false);
    TextView textViewNom = view.findViewById(R.id.labelNom);
    textViewNom.setText(((Main)getActivity()).getNomComplet());
    linearScore = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearScore);
    linearScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        fragment_score frag_score= new fragment_score();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag_score,"scorefrag");
        transaction.addToBackStack("scorefrag");
        transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    linearReglage = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearReglage);
    linearReglage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment_reglage frag_reglage= new fragment_reglage();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag_reglage,"reglagefrag");
            transaction.addToBackStack("reglagefrag");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```