# using Android studio 3.2, i cannot build app for below API 26

Tags: java, android

I created a simple Quiz app on Android Studio 3.2 (Mac), and after compiling the .apk, it gives a Fatal error for Android 6(Marshmallow) and below while working perfectly on Nougat and above. Setting targetSDk below 26 makes an error in my codes while keeping at 26 and above works well.

Error in Logcat showing while running on Marshmallow.

```
06-06 17:16:56.452 10525-10525/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-06 17:16:56.642 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:56.855 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:56.900 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:56.952 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:57.032 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:57.144 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:57.187 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:57.248 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-06 17:16:57.297 10525-10525/com.csstudio.knowledgeablequizz W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43207019/2520628

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "W/art Failed execv" error when I add an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896161/getting-w-art-failed-execv-error-when-i-add-an-imageview)

Comment: what build version are you using?

Comment: build version is 27.0.3

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 Canary 16
Build #AI-181.4668.68.32.4802120, built on May 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b02 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution of this bug from past 2 day and Finally found that my Drawables images were under the folder V24 due to which it was supporting apps above API 24. Now I have moved them to main Drawables folder and it fixed the issue. Thanks everyone who took out time to help me out. :)